# MemoryError in Python when trying to load a big CSV file

Tags: python, r, csv, memory

When I load a big CSV file with pandas I get the following MemoryError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/workspace/loans/src/loans.py", line 100, in <module>
    X_test  =   testdata('test_v2.csv')
  File "/home/k/workspace/loans/src/loans.py", line 18, in testdata
    X   =   pd.read_table(filename, sep=',',    warn_bad_lines=True,    error_bad_lines=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 420, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 225, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 626, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1070, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "parser.pyx", line 727, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:6866)
  File "parser.pyx", line 777, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:7452)
  File "parser.pyx", line 1788, in pandas.parser._concatenate_chunks (pandas/parser.c:20462)
MemoryError
```

The file is of size 1 GB. R opens it without much of a trouble (which is weird because if I understand correctly, R is higher level than Python...)

I am running the code on Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 550  @ 3.20GHz with 4GB RAM. I am running the code on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.

Is there any trick to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is 32-bit or 64-bit python installed? From your `dirs` it looks like Unix?

Comment: As a side-note there is not *the one* criterion whether a language is higher-level-than-X or not. If someone says that, it basically doesn't mean too much. *pandas* might inroduce some overhead (maybe more than R).

Comment: I am running the code on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit

Comment: @UliKöhler Maybe I am misusing the term. I thought that some languages have a more direct access to memory and therefor they are considered to be low-level (such as C++). While languages that are written with C++ and are higher-level will be likely as slow or slower than C++.